# An example on using "zk-SNARK" in "smart contract"?

Tags: privacy, zksnark, zero-knowledge

I read this article: https://media.consensys.net/introduction-to-zksnarks-with-examples-3283b554fc3b

However, it's not clear to me a function such as `zksnarkverify` has been already implemented in Ethereum `Solidity`? Or we need to implement it by our self?

Is there an API or library to use `zk-SNARK` algorithms ? such as:

public keys generator `G(program C, secret lambda) -> (prover public key, verifier public key)`,

or

prover algorithm `P(prover public key, public x, secret w) -> proof`

or

verifier algorithm `V(verifier public key, public x, proof) -> true` ?

where program C is `C(public x, secret w)`.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49781/can-zksnarks-be-implemented-now-on-the-ethereum-ecosystem

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that is in solidity are precompiled contracts for Ellyptic curve operations.

For implementations check out [Is there a decentralized zk-SNARK (zero-knowledge Succinct Non-Interactive ARgument of Knowledge)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57602/is-there-a-decentralized-zk-snark-zero-knowledge-succinct-non-interactive-argum/57617?noredirect=1#comment68892_57617)

Comment: Thanks but we need to implement `verifier algorithm` **on-chain** by `Solidity`. How to do it by `ZoKrates` ? According to its Github [link](https://github.com/JacobEberhardt/ZoKrates) : _"It helps you create offchain programs and link them to the Ethereum blockchain"_

Comment: Creating a ZK Snark generates a solidity contract to deploy on chain.